# 32 bit dll referennce not failing on the 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, 32bit-64bit

I have created a console application. In that application I have referenced a x86 compiled dll. In project settings I changed target platform to x64.

When I run the application (F5) it is throwing the BadImageFormatException. That's ok, but instead of running the application in VS if I just build (build is successful) and copy the .exe file to some other 64 bit OS machine and run the exe it is running fine.

Why it is not failing on the other machine. What is the reason?

My dev machine is 64bit windows 7,VS2010 is 32bit, The other machine is 64bit windows server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Because a 32 bit dll is compatible with a 64 bit CPU, a 64 bit dll on the other hand, is not compatible with a 32 bit CPU.

When you're debugging your application, the debugger expects the application to be 64 bit, that's why it's failing.

Try running it without debugging CTRL+F5 and it will run just fine.

Comment: without debugging also throwing the same exception. My application target platform set to x64. (I have mentioned this in the original question)